# How to make Http request on Android 24

Tags: android

I tried make a Http request on Android 24 using code like

```
url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/";
final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod(method);
conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
conn.connect();
```

First I got an error like

```
java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to 10.0.2.2 not permitted
```

Then I added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to AndroidManifest.xml as some solutions pointed out,
Now I get an error like

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8080
```

The error gives no much useful information, I don't know how to search and solve this error.
The server should be OK, for the code can pass on Android 23.

Comment: The android simulator is corrupted somehow. The built-in web browser doesn't work also. I make a new simulator, and app works.

Answer (score 2):

First check did you added network permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Just add the below code to your manifest file.

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
```

Before you need to create a network rule

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">someDomain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added network permission in manifest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this server in your browser? Address 10.0.2.2 points to your machine's `localhost`. If you open http://localhost:8080
(on computer runnig the emulator) you may get more info about the error. It's worth mentioning, that next to clearTraffic manifest flag, you now need to specify Network security configuration as well:

```
<application
    ....
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_rules" 
    ....
```

Network rules xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">someDomain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using http request. You can use https request to avoid this issue.Try with this for http request.

Put the below line in android manifest under application tag

```
 android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Create xml file inside res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">your domain</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```